# How can I make the paths relative in the application and where do I do that? (MVC4)

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I have a webapplication (MVC4). And I want to publish it. 
When I publish it, I that the paths to the controllers are looking to my directories from my pc and not the paths from my website.

Like this: MyWebApplication\Controllers\HomeController.MyAction() in O:\Developing\MyWebApplication\Controllers\HomeController.cs line 26

Pages without links to the controllers looks fine.

How can I make the paths relative in the application and where do I do that?

There are no further security rules. The hoster has a TrustLevel Medium and only things thare changed by the hoster are:

WebPermission : Unrestricted=”true”

OleDbPermission: Unrestricted=”true”

OdbcPermission : Unrestricted=”true”
ReflectionPermission : Flags=”RestrictedMemberAccess”

and

FileIOPermission : Read=”$AppDir$” PathDiscovery=”$AppDir$” Write=”$AppDir$” Append=”$AppDir$”

This is the source of the stack trace:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Security Exception</title>
        <style>
         body {font-family:"Verdana";font-weight:normal;font-size: .7em;color:black;} 
         p {font-family:"Verdana";font-weight:normal;color:black;margin-top: -5px}
         b {font-family:"Verdana";font-weight:bold;color:black;margin-top: -5px}
         H1 { font-family:"Verdana";font-weight:normal;font-size:18pt;color:red }
         H2 { font-family:"Verdana";font-weight:normal;font-size:14pt;color:maroon }
         pre {font-family:"Lucida Console";font-size: .9em}
         .marker {font-weight: bold; color: black;text-decoration: none;}
         .version {color: gray;}
         .error {margin-bottom: 10px;}
         .expandable { text-decoration:underline; font-weight:bold; color:navy; cursor:hand; }
        </style>
    </head>

    <body bgcolor="white">

            <span><H1>Server Error in '/eHMCWeb' Application.<hr width=100% size=1 color=silver></H1>

            <h2> <i>Security Exception</i> </h2></span>

            <font face="Arial, Helvetica, Geneva, SunSans-Regular, sans-serif ">

            <b> Description: </b>The application attempted to perform an operation not allowed by the security policy. &nbsp;To grant this application the required permission please contact your system administrator or change the application's trust level in the configuration file.
            <br><br>

            <b> Exception Details: </b>System.Security.SecurityException: Request for the permission of type 'System.Security.Permissions.FileIOPermission, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089' failed.<br><br>

            <b>Source Error:</b> <br><br>

            <table width=100% bgcolor="#ffffcc">
               <tr>
                  <td>
                      <code>

An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the current web request. Information regarding the origin and location of the exception can be identified using the exception stack trace below.</code>

                  </td>
               </tr>
            </table>

            <br>

            <b>Stack Trace:</b> <br><br>

            <table width=100% bgcolor="#ffffcc">
               <tr>
                  <td>
                      <code><pre>

[SecurityException: Request for the permission of type &#39;System.Security.Permissions.FileIOPermission, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089&#39; failed.]
   System.Security.CodeAccessSecurityEngine.Check(Object demand, StackCrawlMark&amp; stackMark, Boolean isPermSet) +0
   System.Security.CodeAccessSecurityEngine.Check(CodeAccessPermission cap, StackCrawlMark&amp; stackMark) +31
   System.Security.CodeAccessPermission.Demand() +46
   System.Web.HttpRequest.MapPath(VirtualPath virtualPath, VirtualPath baseVirtualDir, Boolean allowCrossAppMapping) +154
   System.Web.HttpRequest.MapPath(VirtualPath virtualPath) +37
   System.Web.HttpServerUtility.MapPath(String path) +99
   System.Web.HttpServerUtilityWrapper.MapPath(String path) +11
   eHMCWeb.Controllers.Hitlijst.HitlijstController.ReadLijsten(String AItem, Boolean ABeperkt) in HitlijstController.cs:71
   eHMCWeb.Controllers.Hitlijst.HitlijstController.Top10Lijst() in HitlijstController.cs:47
   lambda_method(Closure , ControllerBase , Object[] ) +40
   System.Web.Mvc.ActionMethodDispatcher.Execute(ControllerBase controller, Object[] parameters) +17
   System.Web.Mvc.ReflectedActionDescriptor.Execute(ControllerContext controllerContext, IDictionary`2 parameters) +188
   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionMethod(ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionDescriptor actionDescriptor, IDictionary`2 parameters) +27
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.&lt;&gt;c__DisplayClass42.&lt;BeginInvokeSynchronousActionMethod&gt;b__41() +28
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.&lt;&gt;c__DisplayClass8`1.&lt;BeginSynchronous&gt;b__7(IAsyncResult _) +12
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResult`1.End() +50
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.EndInvokeActionMethod(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +29
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.&lt;&gt;c__DisplayClass39.&lt;BeginInvokeActionMethodWithFilters&gt;b__33() +59
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.&lt;&gt;c__DisplayClass4f.&lt;InvokeActionMethodFilterAsynchronously&gt;b__49() +240
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.&lt;&gt;c__DisplayClass37.&lt;BeginInvokeActionMethodWithFilters&gt;b__36(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +12
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResult`1.End() +50
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.EndInvokeActionMethodWithFilters(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +31
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.&lt;&gt;c__DisplayClass2a.&lt;BeginInvokeAction&gt;b__20() +23
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.&lt;&gt;c__DisplayClass25.&lt;BeginInvokeAction&gt;b__22(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +128
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResult`1.End() +50
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.EndInvokeAction(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +26
   System.Web.Mvc.&lt;&gt;c__DisplayClass1d.&lt;BeginExecuteCore&gt;b__18(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +14
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.&lt;&gt;c__DisplayClass4.&lt;MakeVoidDelegate&gt;b__3(IAsyncResult ar) +25
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResult`1.End() +55
   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.EndExecuteCore(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +41
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.&lt;&gt;c__DisplayClass4.&lt;MakeVoidDelegate&gt;b__3(IAsyncResult ar) +25
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResult`1.End() +55
   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.EndExecute(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +28
   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.System.Web.Mvc.Async.IAsyncController.EndExecute(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +10
   System.Web.Mvc.&lt;&gt;c__DisplayClassb.&lt;BeginProcessRequest&gt;b__4(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +28
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.&lt;&gt;c__DisplayClass4.&lt;MakeVoidDelegate&gt;b__3(IAsyncResult ar) +25
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResult`1.End() +55
   System.Web.Mvc.&lt;&gt;c__DisplayClasse.&lt;EndProcessRequest&gt;b__d() +31
   System.Web.Mvc.SecurityUtil.&lt;GetCallInAppTrustThunk&gt;b__0(Action f) +7
   System.Web.Mvc.SecurityUtil.ProcessInApplicationTrust(Action action) +23
   System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.EndProcessRequest(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +59
   System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.System.Web.IHttpAsyncHandler.EndProcessRequest(IAsyncResult result) +9
   System.Web.Mvc.&lt;&gt;c__DisplayClassa.&lt;EndProcessRequest&gt;b__9() +23
   System.Web.Mvc.&lt;&gt;c__DisplayClass4.&lt;Wrap&gt;b__3() +12
   System.Web.Mvc.ServerExecuteHttpHandlerWrapper.Wrap(Func`1 func) +38
   System.Web.Mvc.ServerExecuteHttpHandlerWrapper.Wrap(Action action) +65
   System.Web.Mvc.ServerExecuteHttpHandlerAsyncWrapper.EndProcessRequest(IAsyncResult result) +70
   System.Web.HttpServerUtility.ExecuteInternal(IHttpHandler handler, TextWriter writer, Boolean preserveForm, Boolean setPreviousPage, VirtualPath path, VirtualPath filePath, String physPath, Exception error, String queryStringOverride) +1067
</pre></code>

                  </td>
               </tr>
            </table>

            <br>

            <hr width=100% size=1 color=silver>

            <b>Version Information:</b>&nbsp;Microsoft .NET Framework Version:4.0.30319; ASP.NET Version:4.0.30319.272

            </font>

    </body>
</html>
<!-- 
[SecurityException]: Request for the permission of type &#39;System.Security.Permissions.FileIOPermission, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089&#39; failed.
   at System.Security.CodeAccessSecurityEngine.Check(Object demand, StackCrawlMark& stackMark, Boolean isPermSet)
   at System.Security.CodeAccessSecurityEngine.Check(CodeAccessPermission cap, StackCrawlMark& stackMark)
   at System.Security.CodeAccessPermission.Demand()
   at System.Web.HttpRequest.MapPath(VirtualPath virtualPath, VirtualPath baseVirtualDir, Boolean allowCrossAppMapping)
   at System.Web.HttpRequest.MapPath(VirtualPath virtualPath)
   at System.Web.HttpServerUtility.MapPath(String path)
   at System.Web.HttpServerUtilityWrapper.MapPath(String path)
   at eHMCWeb.Controllers.Hitlijst.HitlijstController.ReadLijsten(String AItem, Boolean ABeperkt) in O:\eSoft\Extended\eHMCWebSolution\eHMCWeb\Controllers\Hitlijst\HitlijstController.cs:line 71
   at eHMCWeb.Controllers.Hitlijst.HitlijstController.Top10Lijst() in O:\eSoft\Extended\eHMCWebSolution\eHMCWeb\Controllers\Hitlijst\HitlijstController.cs:line 47
   at lambda_method(Closure , ControllerBase , Object[] )
   at System.Web.Mvc.ActionMethodDispatcher.Execute(ControllerBase controller, Object[] parameters)
   at System.Web.Mvc.ReflectedActionDescriptor.Execute(ControllerContext controllerContext, IDictionary`2 parameters)
   at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionMethod(ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionDescriptor actionDescriptor, IDictionary`2 parameters)
   at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.<>c__DisplayClass42.<BeginInvokeSynchronousActionMethod>b__41()
   at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.<>c__DisplayClass8`1.<BeginSynchronous>b__7(IAsyncResult _)
   at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.WrappedAsyncResult`1.End()
   at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.EndInvokeActionMethod(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.<>c__DisplayClass37.<>c__DisplayClass39.<BeginInvokeActionMethodWithFilters>b__33()
   at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.<>c__DisplayClass4f.<InvokeActionMethodFilterAsynchronously>b__49()
   at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.<>c__DisplayClass37.<BeginInvokeActionMethodWithFilters>b__36(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.WrappedAsyncResult`1.End()
   at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.EndInvokeActionMethodWithFilters(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.<>c__DisplayClass25.<>c__DisplayClass2a.<BeginInvokeAction>b__20()
   at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.<>c__DisplayClass25.<BeginInvokeAction>b__22(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.WrappedAsyncResult`1.End()
   at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.EndInvokeAction(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   at System.Web.Mvc.Controller.<>c__DisplayClass1d.<BeginExecuteCore>b__18(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.<>c__DisplayClass4.<MakeVoidDelegate>b__3(IAsyncResult ar)
   at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.WrappedAsyncResult`1.End()
   at System.Web.Mvc.Controller.EndExecuteCore(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.<>c__DisplayClass4.<MakeVoidDelegate>b__3(IAsyncResult ar)
   at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.WrappedAsyncResult`1.End()
   at System.Web.Mvc.Controller.EndExecute(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   at System.Web.Mvc.Controller.System.Web.Mvc.Async.IAsyncController.EndExecute(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   at System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.<>c__DisplayClass6.<>c__DisplayClassb.<BeginProcessRequest>b__4(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.<>c__DisplayClass4.<MakeVoidDelegate>b__3(IAsyncResult ar)
   at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.WrappedAsyncResult`1.End()
   at System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.<>c__DisplayClasse.<EndProcessRequest>b__d()
   at System.Web.Mvc.SecurityUtil.<GetCallInAppTrustThunk>b__0(Action f)
   at System.Web.Mvc.SecurityUtil.ProcessInApplicationTrust(Action action)
   at System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.EndProcessRequest(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   at System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.System.Web.IHttpAsyncHandler.EndProcessRequest(IAsyncResult result)
   at System.Web.Mvc.HttpHandlerUtil.ServerExecuteHttpHandlerAsyncWrapper.<>c__DisplayClassa.<EndProcessRequest>b__9()
   at System.Web.Mvc.HttpHandlerUtil.ServerExecuteHttpHandlerWrapper.<>c__DisplayClass4.<Wrap>b__3()
   at System.Web.Mvc.HttpHandlerUtil.ServerExecuteHttpHandlerWrapper.Wrap[TResult](Func`1 func)
   at System.Web.Mvc.HttpHandlerUtil.ServerExecuteHttpHandlerWrapper.Wrap(Action action)
   at System.Web.Mvc.HttpHandlerUtil.ServerExecuteHttpHandlerAsyncWrapper.EndProcessRequest(IAsyncResult result)
   at System.Web.HttpServerUtility.ExecuteInternal(IHttpHandler handler, TextWriter writer, Boolean preserveForm, Boolean setPreviousPage, VirtualPath path, VirtualPath filePath, String physPath, Exception error, String queryStringOverride)
[HttpException]: Error executing child request for handler &#39;System.Web.Mvc.HttpHandlerUtil+ServerExecuteHttpHandlerAsyncWrapper&#39;.
   at System.Web.HttpServerUtility.ExecuteInternal(IHttpHandler handler, TextWriter writer, Boolean preserveForm, Boolean setPreviousPage, VirtualPath path, VirtualPath filePath, String physPath, Exception error, String queryStringOverride)
   at System.Web.HttpServerUtility.Execute(IHttpHandler handler, TextWriter writer, Boolean preserveForm, Boolean setPreviousPage)
   at System.Web.HttpServerUtility.Execute(IHttpHandler handler, TextWriter writer, Boolean preserveForm)
   at System.Web.HttpServerUtilityWrapper.Execute(IHttpHandler handler, TextWriter writer, Boolean preserveForm)
   at System.Web.Mvc.Html.ChildActionExtensions.ActionHelper(HtmlHelper htmlHelper, String actionName, String controllerName, RouteValueDictionary routeValues, TextWriter textWriter)
   at System.Web.Mvc.Html.ChildActionExtensions.Action(HtmlHelper htmlHelper, String actionName, String controllerName, RouteValueDictionary routeValues)
   at System.Web.Mvc.Html.ChildActionExtensions.Action(HtmlHelper htmlHelper, String actionName)
   at ASP.views_hitlijst_home_aspx.__RenderContent2(HtmlTextWriter __w, Control parameterContainer) in d:\www\alerdoor.nl\www\eHMCWeb\Views\Hitlijst\Home.aspx:line 12
   at System.Web.UI.Control.RenderChildrenInternal(HtmlTextWriter writer, ICollection children)
   at System.Web.UI.Control.RenderChildren(HtmlTextWriter writer)
   at System.Web.UI.Control.Render(HtmlTextWriter writer)
   at System.Web.UI.Control.RenderControlInternal(HtmlTextWriter writer, ControlAdapter adapter)
   at System.Web.UI.Control.RenderControl(HtmlTextWriter writer, ControlAdapter adapter)
   at System.Web.UI.Control.RenderControl(HtmlTextWriter writer)
   at ASP.views_shared_site_master.__Render__control1(HtmlTextWriter __w, Control parameterContainer) in d:\www\alerdoor.nl\www\eHMCWeb\Views\Shared\Site.Master:line 66
   at System.Web.UI.Control.RenderChildrenInternal(HtmlTextWriter writer, ICollection children)
   at System.Web.UI.Control.RenderChildren(HtmlTextWriter writer)
   at System.Web.UI.Control.Render(HtmlTextWriter writer)
   at System.Web.UI.Control.RenderControlInternal(HtmlTextWriter writer, ControlAdapter adapter)
   at System.Web.UI.Control.RenderControl(HtmlTextWriter writer, ControlAdapter adapter)
   at System.Web.UI.Control.RenderControl(HtmlTextWriter writer)
   at System.Web.UI.Control.RenderChildrenInternal(HtmlTextWriter writer, ICollection children)
   at System.Web.UI.Control.RenderChildren(HtmlTextWriter writer)
   at System.Web.Mvc.ViewPage.Render(HtmlTextWriter writer)
   at System.Web.UI.Control.RenderControlInternal(HtmlTextWriter writer, ControlAdapter adapter)
   at System.Web.UI.Control.RenderControl(HtmlTextWriter writer, ControlAdapter adapter)
   at System.Web.UI.Control.RenderControl(HtmlTextWriter writer)
   at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)
   at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequest(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)
   at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequest()
   at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestWithNoAssert(HttpContext context)
   at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
   at System.Web.Mvc.ViewPage.ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
   at ASP.views_hitlijst_home_aspx.ProcessRequest(HttpContext context) in c:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files\ehmcweb\211ce6d5\c53b05ec\App_Web_ncv2y2gm.2.cs:line 0
   at System.Web.Mvc.HttpHandlerUtil.ServerExecuteHttpHandlerWrapper.<>c__DisplayClass1.<ProcessRequest>b__0()
   at System.Web.Mvc.HttpHandlerUtil.ServerExecuteHttpHandlerWrapper.<>c__DisplayClass4.<Wrap>b__3()
   at System.Web.Mvc.HttpHandlerUtil.ServerExecuteHttpHandlerWrapper.Wrap[TResult](Func`1 func)
   at System.Web.Mvc.HttpHandlerUtil.ServerExecuteHttpHandlerWrapper.Wrap(Action action)
   at System.Web.Mvc.HttpHandlerUtil.ServerExecuteHttpHandlerWrapper.ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
   at System.Web.HttpServerUtility.ExecuteInternal(IHttpHandler handler, TextWriter writer, Boolean preserveForm, Boolean setPreviousPage, VirtualPath path, VirtualPath filePath, String physPath, Exception error, String queryStringOverride)
[HttpException]: Error executing child request for handler &#39;System.Web.Mvc.HttpHandlerUtil+ServerExecuteHttpHandlerWrapper&#39;.
   at System.Web.HttpServerUtility.ExecuteInternal(IHttpHandler handler, TextWriter writer, Boolean preserveForm, Boolean setPreviousPage, VirtualPath path, VirtualPath filePath, String physPath, Exception error, String queryStringOverride)
   at System.Web.HttpServerUtility.Execute(IHttpHandler handler, TextWriter writer, Boolean preserveForm, Boolean setPreviousPage)
   at System.Web.HttpServerUtility.Execute(IHttpHandler handler, TextWriter writer, Boolean preserveForm)
   at System.Web.HttpServerUtilityWrapper.Execute(IHttpHandler handler, TextWriter writer, Boolean preserveForm)
   at System.Web.Mvc.ViewPage.RenderView(ViewContext viewContext)
   at System.Web.Mvc.WebFormView.RenderViewPage(ViewContext context, ViewPage page)
   at System.Web.Mvc.WebFormView.RenderView(ViewContext viewContext, TextWriter writer, Object instance)
   at System.Web.Mvc.BuildManagerCompiledView.Render(ViewContext viewContext, TextWriter writer)
   at System.Web.Mvc.ViewResultBase.ExecuteResult(ControllerContext context)
   at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResult(ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionResult actionResult)
   at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.<>c__DisplayClass1a.<InvokeActionResultWithFilters>b__17()
   at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResultFilter(IResultFilter filter, ResultExecutingContext preContext, Func`1 continuation)
   at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.<>c__DisplayClass1a.<>c__DisplayClass1c.<InvokeActionResultWithFilters>b__19()
   at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResultWithFilters(ControllerContext controllerContext, IList`1 filters, ActionResult actionResult)
   at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.<>c__DisplayClass25.<>c__DisplayClass2a.<BeginInvokeAction>b__20()
   at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.<>c__DisplayClass25.<BeginInvokeAction>b__22(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.WrappedAsyncResult`1.End()
   at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.EndInvokeAction(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   at System.Web.Mvc.Controller.<>c__DisplayClass1d.<BeginExecuteCore>b__18(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.<>c__DisplayClass4.<MakeVoidDelegate>b__3(IAsyncResult ar)
   at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.WrappedAsyncResult`1.End()
   at System.Web.Mvc.Controller.EndExecuteCore(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.<>c__DisplayClass4.<MakeVoidDelegate>b__3(IAsyncResult ar)
   at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.WrappedAsyncResult`1.End()
   at System.Web.Mvc.Controller.EndExecute(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   at System.Web.Mvc.Controller.System.Web.Mvc.Async.IAsyncController.EndExecute(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   at System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.<>c__DisplayClass6.<>c__DisplayClassb.<BeginProcessRequest>b__4(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.<>c__DisplayClass4.<MakeVoidDelegate>b__3(IAsyncResult ar)
   at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.WrappedAsyncResult`1.End()
   at System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.<>c__DisplayClasse.<EndProcessRequest>b__d()
   at System.Web.Mvc.SecurityUtil.<GetCallInAppTrustThunk>b__0(Action f)
   at System.Web.Mvc.SecurityUtil.ProcessInApplicationTrust(Action action)
   at System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.EndProcessRequest(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   at System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.System.Web.IHttpAsyncHandler.EndProcessRequest(IAsyncResult result)
   at System.Web.HttpApplication.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute()
   at System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously)
--><!-- 
This error page might contain sensitive information because ASP.NET is configured to show verbose error messages using &lt;customErrors mode="Off"/&gt;. Consider using &lt;customErrors mode="On"/&gt; or &lt;customErrors mode="RemoteOnly"/&gt; in production environments.-->
```

Comment: Where is generating file-system links? Do you mean the debugging symbols when you get an exception?

Comment: When I open a page with an link to a controller, you get a stack trace. And when I open the view of the source, you see a text with the path.

Comment: You normally only get a stack trace if there is a problem...

Comment: There is a problem that's reason for my question. (Sorry for my reaction.)

Comment: @user1531040 - You are misunderstanding what you're seeing.  When the application is compiled, the stack trace includes the paths to the locations in which the original code was compiled at, so you can find this code again later.  It is not actually trying to access those paths.  Your problem is something else, and MVC is showing you a stack trace to help you find the problem, but without you posting the error and/or the stack trace, we can't help you.

Comment: Okay I've updated my question. And added the whole source of the stack trace. I thought I've given enough information.

Comment: The only relevant information is the path you're handing to `HitlijstController.ReadLijsten()`, the code that's in there and the path your code finally tries to access. Please edit your question to show this information.

Comment: It looks like you're trying to set file permissions. The user your site is running under may not be allowed to change those at runtime, especially if this site is on a shared hosting platform.

Comment: What does line `71` of `HitlijstController` say?

Comment: The item gets a gets a default value "50" and beperkt gets the value true.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may write

```
var path="~/AnyFolderInYourSolutionExplorer/,,,,,,";
~ is replaced with path to your project.
```

For example if In my MVC app, a Folder named as "Images" contans my photo, then to access that one is as

```
var img="~/Images/myPhoto.jpg";
```

Comment: And where can I do that? Here: <li>@Html.ActionLink("My Description", "~/Controllers/HomeController/MyActon", "Home")</li> My system can't find the controller.

Comment: @user1531040 That's not how you use the `HtmlHelper` class. Assuming the action you're trying to build a link for is `MyAction`, you'd use `@Html.ActionLink("My Description", "MyAction", "Home")` - the routing rules in `RouteConfig` are used to figure out where you're trying to link to.

Comment: I know but I still doesn't work. See stack trace. But I can only debugging in LocalHost. How can I see how the route works on the internet. And on localhost all works fine.

Comment: The application on the internet looks to the paht on my local machine. That's my problem.

Comment: @user1531040 No it doesn't, the debugging information file (PDB) is storing the information about the original source file which the stack trace is using to tell you where the error is. The key issue is you are actually getting an exception generated by your HitlijstController at line 71

Comment: I found the problem. Sometimes I forgot the "~", and sometimes not. And I was blind to see what was the real problem, because of the path the stack trace gave.

Answer (score 1):

you should just be able to specify the action and controller (without the controller suffix)
MVC is smart enough to look for the controller. so this should work:

```
@Html.ActionLink("description","MyAction","Home")
```

Answer (score 1):

In MVC 4 all you need to do is:

```
 <img src="~/SomeFolder/someImage.jpg" />
```

The ~ symbol ensures that MVC will look for the file in the root of your website whereever it might be. Prior to MVC 4 you had to do this:

```
 <img src="@Url.Content("~/SomeFolder/someImage.jpg")" />
```